# What is a general term for or expression for posing or taking a stance before a physical challenge?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm thinking of the way someone squats before shooting a basketball, or gets into the push off position for a race, or even taking a breath before singing a loud note. What would be an good word or idiom to collectively describe the moment where one physically prepares for a challenge?

Comment: Maybe, “*getting ready to **put their all into it***”

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a *poise* here or *poised* e.g.

> He is poised for the start of the race
>
> She is poised to shoot for the hoop
>
> She has the perfect poise to strike the ball cleanly

Comment: Ok for a singer or dancer. But is *poise* something one associates with "real men"? Somehow I can't think of Rooney, "poised" to take the penalty kick! Perhaps he would be "readying himself" for the kick which would decide the match.

Comment: On the contrary, @WS2, I _would_ think of soccer players preparing for free kicks and rugby players preparing for conversions as being poised. Also how much more 'real man' do you want than Moby Dick? _Ahab ... was even thus close to him; when, with body arched back, and both arms lengthwise high-lifted to the **poise**, he darted his fierce iron, and his far fiercer curse into the hated whale_. Having said that I like 'readying himself'. It includes preparations without a strong element of physical balance better.

Comment: @BoldBen Oh, well - point taken! But always remember "soccer" is a women's game! Men play "football".

Answer (score 1):

In racing, you *take your mark, **set**, go*. You get *set*.

> 3:  to place (oneself) in position to start running in a race

"Set." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 12 Sept. 2016.

It seems to work for the other example as well. I found multiple hits for *get set to make a freethrow* and for photo captions reading *... gets set to sing the National Anthem.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest either

- ***[ready to roll](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ready+to+roll)***

> prepared to start doing something

or

- ***[raring to go](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raring+to+go)***

> to be ready and excited to begin doing something

[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms via The Free Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

In US military-speak and/or in the situation of a police officer arresting a person, **assume the position** is a formal way of issuing an order or instruction for someone to comply *physically* with what is required to happen next. In the case of an army sergeant-instructor ordering a GI-in-training to get down and do "50-push-ups", **assume the position** is a common order/instruction to do just that.

Likewise when a police officer is in the process of arresting a *compliant* person, he might well say this in the expectation that the person will put his hands behind his back to facilitate being handcuffed and/or spread his legs and put his outstretched arms up against a wall and/or on the hood (AmE) of a car so as to facilitate the police officer carrying out a superficial search for weapons or contraband.

**Assume the position:** (verb) 1. Often used other than as an idiom: to assume a given position.
2. (idiomatic, US, law enforcement). To turn away, with your hands in a visible position so that you can be searched. (YourDictionary online)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider ***warm-up***!

M-W:

> **[warm–up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warm-up)**
>   *noun*
>
> 1 :  the act or an instance of **warming up**; also :  **a preparatory
>   activity or procedure**

Wikipedia:

> [**Warming-up**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warming_up) is performed before a performance or practice.
>   Athletes, singers, actors and others warm up before stressing their
>   muscles. it prepares the muscles for vigorous actions.
>
> **A warm up** generally consists of a gradual increase in intensity in
>   physical activity (a "pulse raiser"), joint mobility exercise, and
>   stretching, followed by the activity. Warming up brings the body to a
>   condition at which it safely responds to nerve signals for quick and
>   efficient action.

Comment: But this is not what a racer is doing when he is getting into position in the blocks not is it what a singer is doing when they take a deep breath prior to letting loose a loud note.

Comment: They are preparatory activities and by definition in M-W form part of warm up (which can additionally include other, more _physical_ activities too). And yes, taking a deep breath before letting out a loud note is akin to stretching limbs before a run, don't you think?

Comment: No I don’t. I am picturing this breath as *the* breath that when released makes that note, not a preparatory exercise.  And when the racer is told, “On your marks... Get set...” the following actions are no longer part of a racer’s warmup activities, at that point he is “in the race”